# R tm package - Removing whole paragraph

Tags: r, text, mining

I am trying to remove whole paragraph that keeps repeating in different documents. It is a disclaimer that goes at the end of an email e.g : " any review, retransmission  dissemination or other use of this email...."

```
docs<-Corpus(VectorSource(text$Description))
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/|@|\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
   docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, paste0(
  "any ",
  "review ",
  "retransmission, ",
  "dissemination ...)
```

It is not working. I can't remove individual words as some of them may be valuable...any suggestions?

Comment: I can show you how to do this if you make the example reproducible

Comment: Sorry...not sure how to do that. Can you show me using any sentence as an example?